# Understanding 'echo' service example API from Servant paper

Tags: api, haskell, servant

The introduction of the [servant paper](https://www.andres-loeh.de/Servant/servant-wgp.pdf) contains the following example API type:

```
type Echo = "echo"
          :> ReqBody ’[PlainText] String
          :> Get ’[PlainText] String
```

I am attempting to understand this example. It appears to be defining a type synonym, but seems to involve some things that I have not seen before.

Here are three questions that I have about it:

1. **How is there a string literal in the definition of a type?**

`"echo"` is a string literal. I thought these were only used to define specific strings and don't know what this means when used in a type declaration.

2. **What is the symbol `:>`?**

The definition of this symbol in the 'servant' package appears to be [defined here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-0.11/docs/Servant-API-Sub.html#t::-62-) and looks like this:

```
data (path :: k) :> a
    deriving (Typeable)
infixr 9 :>
```

I would guess that `:>` corresponds to a `/` in an api string, but do not see how this definition would make that happen.

This is the first time I am seeing a non-alphanumeric type other than  the function type `->`.

3. **What does the apostrophe before the list type mean?**

`[PlainText]` I would understand to simply represent a list of PlainText elements, but in contrast I do not understand what `’[PlainText]` means.

Comment: This is the `DataKinds` extension at work, allowing one to (roughly) lift values at the type level. Using that, one can define a type which depends on _values_ rather than other types as usual. This is why strings can appear there. At the type level, `[T]` stands for the type list-of-T, while `'[x]` stands for the (lifted) value "list containing only one element `x`". One could even write `'[x,y,z]`, for instance.

Comment: The paper does quite a good job of explaining in more detail how things are implemented in the later sections, without assuming too much knowledge, so I'd recommend you keep reading :). I also found the [Tiny Servant](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/2015/11/implementing-a-minimal-version-of-haskell-servant/) article by Andres Löh was a nice intoduction before reading the full paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is there a string literal in the definition of a type?

The [`DataKinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDataKinds) extension lets you use these string literals in type signatures. Each one of them represents a different type. They all belong to the kind [`Symbol`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol); we can test this using the `:kind` command in ghci:

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds
Prelude> :kind "foo"
"foo" :: GHC.Types.Symbol
```

Because in Haskell only types of kind `*` have values, these type-level strings are not inhabited. But there are [functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:symbolVal) that let you obtain the corresponding term-level string anyway.

> What is the symbol :>?

The [`TypeOperators`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#type-operators) extension lets you define types with operator names. This is useful for parameterized types that are mostly used to combine other types. Notice that `:>` has two  type parameters but no value-level constructors: it is only used at the type level.

> What does the apostrophe before the list type mean?

`DataKinds` does more than enabling symbols. It lets you use value constructors as *types*, and the types of these constructors become *kinds* in its turn. For example:

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds
Prelude> :kind True
True :: Bool
```

These promoted constructors are not inhabited by any term (because they have kinds other than `*`).

In particular, we can promote lists to the type-level. But this creates some ambiguity. What is `[Int]` in a signature? Is it the type of lists of `Int`s (that has kind `*`) or is it a type-level list with one element, the type `Int`? The apostrophe makes clear that we are talking about the type-level list.

```
Prelude> :set -XDataKinds
Prelude> :kind [Int]
[Int] :: *
Prelude> :kind '[Int]
'[Int] :: [*]
Prelude> :kind '[True]
'[True] :: [Bool]
```

Type-level lists of more than one element don't require the apostrophe, because there's no ambiguity:

```
Prelude> :kind [Int,Int]
[Int,Int] :: [*]
```